# Different - Repeated Pattern of UITableViewCells

Tags: uitableview, swift, custom-cell

I have a `UITableView` with four different custom `UITableViewCell`s. I need to repeat each cell type as follows:

```
row 0 -> cell1
row 1 -> cell2
row 2 -> cell3
row 3 -> cell4
row 4 -> cell1
row 5 -> cell2
row 6 -> cell3
row 7 -> cell4
row 8 -> cell1
...
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, just follow these steps (I assume you have made four prototype cells in the storyboard):

1. Open your storyboard, and select the first cell (be sure the `UITableViewCell` is selected, and not its content view)
2. On the right side of the storyboard, in the attributes inspector, type in a custom identifier to identify this cell in the box labelled **reuse identifier** (for this example, I'll name it **cell1**)
3. Repeat this for the other three cells (these subsequent cells will have the identifiers **cell2, cell3, and cell4**
4. Back in the `UITableViewDataSource` class, override the function `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
5. In this function, get the `indexPath.row`'s modulo (%) by 4. If this value is 0, then do `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1")` if it is 1, then replace it with cell2, and so on. In code, step 5 looks something like this -

   ```
   switch indexPath.row % 4 {

   case 0:
   let cell = tableView.deqeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1")

   case 1:
   let cell = tableView.deqeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2")

   case 2:
   let cell = tableView.deqeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell3")

   case 3:
   let cell = tableView.deqeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell4")

   }

   return cell
   ```

Just put this code in the function mentioned in step 4, and you can build and run. Hope this works!

Comment: `let reuseid = ["cell1", "cell2", "cell3", "cell4"][indexPath.row % 4]`

Answer (score 0):

The cells are to be created in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where the indexpath is passed as a parameter. With `indexPath.row` you can calculate what cell type needs to be used.

`indexPath.row` modulo 4 gives the cell number type.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellNumber = indexPath.row % 4

    if cellNumber == 0 {  // row 0, 4, 8, ...
        // create cell1
    }
    else if cellNumber == 1 {  // row 1, 5, 9, ...
        // create cell2
    }
    else if cellNumber == 2 {  // row 2, 6, 10, ...
        // create cell3
    }
    else if cellNumber == 3 {  // row 3, 7, 11, ...
        // create cell4
    }

}
```